# Bootstrap 4 DateTimePicker start week on monday

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In the [Bootstrap 4 datetimepicker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/), how do I make the weeks start on Monday instead of Sunday?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you commented, this does not appear to be true for this library

> You can do that in the options, while initiating your datepicker
>
> ```
> $('#yourElement').datetimepicker({
>     weekStart: 1
> });
> ```
>
> This changes the first day of the week in your perspective.

I thought I knew this library :) But [this one](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) does support weekStart and basically provides the same functionality.

However, changing the locale does work and is the preferred way. These libraries work with moment.js.

```
$('#yourElement').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en' // or whatever your locale is, 'ru' for example
});
```

This works because whatever your locale's first DOW is, moment.js will alter that accordingly [as explained here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/). You can use this method if you want to support other locales automatically.

For example, you might be able to determine the client's locale and pass that directly into the datepicker:

```
    locale: navigator.language || 'en'
```

Besides, you can find all the info on the page you included in your question :)

Comment: Are we talking about the same datetimepicker library? I'm not seeing the "weekStart" option in this library. Can you follow that link and check?

Comment: @J.Knapp I changed my answer, I tried a lot of libraries before and was too fast assuming this option was implemented

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I had no idea that european countries start on monday not sunday. Fascinating.