# Begin input type="date" with monday

Tags: html

Is it possible to begin a input type="date" with monday instead of sunday?

I currently have this:

```html
<input type="date" id="selectedDate" name="selectedDate">
```

but I need it to start with monday (for german users).

Comment: Do you have the German locale set in the browser? E.g. if it's running on a German-localized OS (or in Chromium-based browser set the locale on the **Sensors** tab in dev tools)?

Comment: [This is same Question you asked they just use simple JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008392/bootstrap-4-datetimepicker-start-week-on-monday)
I think this will help you

Comment: @MuhammadAwais I tried their solution with setting the locale to 'de', but it did not change anything.

Comment: @tromgy I'm working with a german localized OS. The website is for a german company.

Comment: I think this is based on browser locale, you do not control it. For me in the snippet it starts from monday.

Comment: you could try to use Jquery UI Datepicker, you could set your locale in your datepicker

Answer (score -2):

flatpickr("#selectedDate",  {
dateFormat: "Y-m-d", // MM-DD-YYYY format
locale: {
firstDayOfWeek: 1 // Monday as the first day of the week.
}
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).